# Vb-script parse webpages with username and password

Tags: vbscript, html

***NOTE: I need to use something like Vb-Script or batch because that is what i am familiar with and i also need to be able to run, edit, and create files.***

I need to name MS Word files values on a webpage. I decided to first download the webpage as HTML using this code:

```
function download(sFileURL, sLocation, async)
  set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  objXMLHTTP.open "GET", sFileURL, async
  on error resume next
  objXMLHTTP.send()
  if err.number = 0 then
    do until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200
      wscript.echo objXMLHTTP.Status
      wcript.sleep(200)
    loop
    if objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1
      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    
      set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      If objFSO.Fileexists(sLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile sLocation
      Set objFSO = Nothing
      objADOStream.SaveToFile sLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      set objADOStream = Nothing
      download = true
    end if
  else
    download = false
  end if
  set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
end function

if download("https://web.example.com\login.php", "C:\", false) then
  wscript.echo "download ok"
else
  wscript.echo "download nok"
end if
```

The only problem is that to view this page you need to be logged in with a username and password.

***NOTE: I can't use the actual webpage for security reasons.***

Comment: You need to pass both your username and password to the login page in an XMLHTTP `POST` before doing a `GET`.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this? I'm not very familiar with vbscript I prefer to use batch but it is impossible.